# How can I listen udp port in PHP and write logs in a text file?

Tags: php, sockets

I need to listen udp port in PHP and record log data in a text file.

I have tried to listen 514 port but page has waiting until i close the web service xampp.

```
<?php 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 1223);
$from = '';
$port = 514;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);
?>
```

Comment: This may help you: https://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

Comment: Thank you, but it has not include a solution about my problem.